# Problem pictures display in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimageview

I download asynchronously some pictures and store them in an NSMutableDictonnary with picture URL as key (to avoid to download two times the same picture).

After I try to display these pictures in a tableView but when I display the same picture two times the first one is removed!

I really don't understand why?

Please help, that make me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AsiHttpRequest and know i works very well.

allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: Are you saying this answered your question?  or are you trying to add a comment?

Comment: Yes, AsiHttpRequest fixed my problem, so it's my answer for this question.